# How to access node x and y in D3.js version 4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to follow this example and draw a tree layout with D3.js:

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/08ecb6ea9bb68ba0d9a7e89f344acec8

I get an errors ' attribute d: Expected number, "Mundefined,undefined"' and ' attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(undefined,undefined)"'.

When I try to log d.x and d.y I get undefined:

```
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data( nodes.descendants().slice(1))
  .enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "link")
.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.data.level; })
.attr("d", function(d) {
   console.log(d.x, d.y) // undefined undefined
   return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
     + "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.x
     + " " + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.parent.x
     + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
   });
```

How do I get the node x and y values? Or do I need to assign them somewhere?

Also what I don't get in the example is that isn't the selectAll supposed to get the existing elements? This code is confusing for me, since I thought this is where the links are generated but on the other hand it uses selectAll method to ".link". So what is exactly happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the node x and y values? Or do I need to assign them
>   somewhere?

In your code the `x` and `y` values are derived from `nodes.descendants().slice(1)` which is used as a parameter in `.data()`. So whatever `x` and `y` values you have in `nodes.descendants().slice(1)` can be used later.

> Also what I don't get in the example is that isn't the selectAll
>   supposed to get the existing elements?

To paraphrase a great [tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data):

> So you might imagine something like this would be helpful
>
> ```
> var link = g.selectAll(".link")
> ```
>
> and you’d be right, but there’s a catch: The paragraphs we want to
>   select don’t exist yet. And this gets at one of the most common points
>   of confusion with D3: How can we select elements that don’t yet exist?
>   Bear with me, as the answer may require bending your mind a bit.

The links don't exist yet but your `enter()` command creates them